# Can I tell HTML agility pack to NOT fix some types of invalid markup?

Tags: umbraco, html-agility-pack

I have HTML agility pack modifying some of my html within the umbraco CMS, however umbraco uses some non-standard html-oid (See below)

The problem is after the html agility pack replaces the closing slash with a question mark.

macro tag before html agility pack:

```
<?UMBRACO_MACRO macroAlias="RandomMacroTest" />
```

macro tag after html agility pack:

```
<?umbraco_macro macroalias="RandomMacroTest"?>
```

Any clues how I could get around this? Tell Html Agility pack to ignore this tag? I've looked at it's various options and none of them seem to apply.

Last resort: to go back and re-fix the macro tags with a regex replace, but that seems a bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the `OptionWriteEmptyNodes` option on the document.  It should preserve that tag.

```cs
var htmlStr = @"<?UMBRACO_MACRO macroAlias=""RandomMacroTest"" />";
var doc = new HtmlDocument
{
    OptionOutputOriginalCase = true,
    OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true,
};
doc.LoadHtml(htmlStr);
doc.Save(Console.Out);
```

You will have the output:

```html
<?UMBRACO_MACRO macroalias="RandomMacroTest" />
```

Comment: Though I'm not sure what to do about the casing of the attribute.